# OutOfMemoryError during BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray for taken picture with Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: android, android-camera, out-of-memory

I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryError` while creating a `Bitmap` from a picture taken from the `Camera`. My code works fine a couple times until I get the exception, so I spent several hours looking for memory leaks.

The weird thing is, I traced the code up to my `PictureCallback` just to check the byte array size: it's about 280k when no exception is thrown, but eventually, I receive a byte array of more than 1.2M, and that's when decodeByteArray crashes.

I'm using a custom `CameraActivity`. The code to init the `Camera` looks like this

```
camera = Camera.open();
camera.setDisplayOrientation(cameraOrientation);            
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
Size size = getPreferredPictureSize();
params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
params.setJpegQuality(JPEG_QUALITY);
params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
camera.stopPreview();
camera.setParameters(params);
camera.startPreview();
```

When my `CameraActivity` is paused I release de `Camera` like this

```
if (camera != null) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

Why the returned picture can have so different sizes given the same initialization? May I missing some way to totally release the `Camera` stuff? Any clue is appreciated :)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan. I'm aware of the Android docs for displaying bitmaps, but I guess my issue is more Camera related; still can't understand why the resulting byte array size vary so much.

Comment: @ssantos Any solutions yet?

Comment: @shawndreck, it's been a while since I struggled with this one, but regarding the varying picture size issue, I remember I had to setup camera parameters just before every picture. I'm posting my `CameraUtils` class, hopefully you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found several issues here, but I managed to stop receiving different sized arrays by resetting my camera parameters every time I take a picture. Here it is my `CameraUtils` implementation, just in case someone find it useful.

```
import java.util.List;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;

public class CameraUtils implements Camera.AutoFocusCallback {
    private static CameraUtils singleton = null;
    private Camera camera = null;
    private boolean isFocusing;
    private PictureCallback pictureCallback;
    private int cameraOrientation = 90; 
    private Size pictureSize;
    private final String CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_ON = "on";
    private final String CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_OFF = "off";
    private final int PHOTO_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD = 960;
    private final int JPEG_QUALITY = 90;    
    private String cameraFlashMode;
    private float defaultCameraRatio;

    private CameraUtils() {
    }

    public static CameraUtils getInstance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            singleton = new CameraUtils();
        }

        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
        isFocusing = false;

        if (CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_ON.equals(cameraFlashMode)) {
            setFlashEnabled(true);
        }

        if (pictureCallback != null) {
            setupParameters();
            Application.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().showLoading();
            camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkCameraHardware() {
        if (Application.getContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Camera getCamera() throws Exception {
        if (camera == null) {
            isFocusing = false;
            pictureCallback = null;
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(cameraOrientation);
            setupParameters();
        }
        return camera;
    }

    public void setupParameters() {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        defaultCameraRatio = (float) params.getPictureSize().width / (float) params.getPictureSize().height;
        Size size = getPreferredPictureSize();
        params.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
        params.setJpegQuality(JPEG_QUALITY);
        params.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);    
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        pictureSize = size;
    }

    public void autofocus(boolean forceAutofocus) {
        if (camera != null && (!isFocusing || forceAutofocus)) {
            camera.cancelAutoFocus();
            disableFlash();
            isFocusing = true;
            camera.autoFocus(this);
        }
    }

    public void releaseCamera() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    public void setFlashEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if (camera != null) {
            if (enabled) {
                if (camera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes().contains(CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
                    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_ON);
                    camera.setParameters(params);

                    cameraFlashMode = CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_ON;
                }
            } else {
                if (camera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes().contains(CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
                    Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                    params.setFlashMode(CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);

                    cameraFlashMode = CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_OFF;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void disableFlash() {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(CAMERA_FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
    }

    public void takePhoto(PictureCallback pictureCallback) throws Exception {
        this.pictureCallback = pictureCallback;
        autofocus(true);
    }

    private Size getPreferredPictureSize() {
        Size res = null;
        List<Size> sizes = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();

        for (Size s : sizes) {
            float ratio = (float) s.width / (float) s.height;
            if (ratio == defaultCameraRatio && s.height <= PHOTO_HEIGHT_THRESHOLD) {
                res = s;
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    public Size getPictureSize() {
        return pictureSize;
    }   
}
```